# is there a way to output a square root in a square root form instead of a read number with python?

Tags: python

there are a lot of tools could be used to compute square roots.

for instance, with Python NumPy

```
np.sqrt(80)
```

outputs

```
8.94427190999916
```

is there a way (or a 3rd party package) to have

```
sqrt(80)
```

output

$4\sqrt{5}$

Comment: This is not a math question, rather a programming question, so I've voted to close. But what you want is sympy.

Comment: you could write code to solve the equation $$n=x\sqrt{y}$$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers. Giving this function the value of $n$, you get back $x,y$. You could then format the output as you desire. In your case, $n=8.94427190999916$, $x=4$ and $y=5$. It maybe good to include this fact in your question text. The problem boils down to converting an irrational number to an expression with a root. However, I don't think it is always possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sympy](https://live.sympy.org/) could meet your need

```
sqrt(80)
```

outputs $4\sqrt{5}$

[image]